# SwiftUI NSAttributedString gradient foreground color

Tags: swiftui, gradient, nsattributedstring, stroke

I am using this code. How can I add GradientColor to strokeColor ?
strokeColor only accepts UIColor. Can I cast GradientColor to UIColor?

**I want to do this.:**

```
NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor: LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
```

**My Code:**

```
struct StrokeTextLabel: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var fontName: String
    @Binding var text: String
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        let attributedStringParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        attributedStringParagraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(
            string: text,
            attributes:[
                NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: attributedStringParagraphStyle,
                NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth: 3.0,
                NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor: UIColor.red,// How can I change Gradient
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: fontName, size:30.0)!
            ]
        )

        let strokeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        
        
        strokeLabel.attributedText = attributedString
        strokeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        strokeLabel.sizeToFit()
        strokeLabel.center = CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        
        return strokeLabel
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a gradient as a color; it isn't a color. A common technique in many situations is to use your text as a *mask* to reveal the gradient *behind* it. For example, that is an easy way to paint your text with a color-change that flows from top to bottom or from left to right.

A great deal, however, depends upon the exact details of what you want to do with the gradient.